# Drupal Multi-sites without Shared Configuration?

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I am on the development team for a client who has a multisite Drupal setup on Acquia Site Factory.
We have three groups of sites having around 40%~50% of the functionality same across.

We are trying to create a setup where the three websites can be handled using three different configuration folders so that the teams working will not affect the other two site's configurations if one site's configuration changes.

Example of what we are trying to do :

config folders:

- groupa(config/groupa)

  - default
  - site1
  - site2
  - site3
- groupb(config/groupb)

  - default
  - site1
  - site2
  - site3
- groupb

  - default(config/groupb)
  - site1
  - site2
  - site3

Answer (score 0):

Use [multisite](https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal) option and also you can use [Configuration Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) module to split configurations between environments like prod/local/staging.

Comment: I already know this. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh, I see you need to have one more level in multisite.  I didn't see a such configuration before. Can suggest to install three different installations of each group.

Comment: Yeah that's a problem as the client has bought a single subscription for all the three types of sites to host

Comment: Multisite plus domain module to manage each groups?